Parse csv file with cell having comma and quotes using spark
My CSV file has more than 30 columns such that some of the columns represents json string like -
"{""name"": ""value1"",""name2"": ""value2""}"
I'm trying to parse this csv file using scala spark. But the values after , is being treaded as a separate column instead of same column.
This is how I'm reading the csv file:
val spark = SparkSession.builder
  .appName("ReadCSVExample")
  .master("local")  // Set your master URL appropriately
  .getOrCreate()

val csvOptions = Map(
  "header" -> "true",          // If CSV has header row
)

val df: DataFrame = spark.read.options(csvOptions).csv(csvFilePath)

I have already tried "escapeQuote" to true but it didn't work. can someone pls help

Use these options to escape quotes:
.option("quote", "\"")
.option("escape", "\"")

